# Pre-conditions for rule execution in Drools Workbench (7.15)

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

We have a decision table that should not be executed unless a field value of one of our fact objects matches one in a (potentially long) list of lookup values. The decision table content is managed by non-technical users and we are looking for a way to allow those same non-technical users to manage the list of lookup values.

Here is an assessment of various approaches we've identified using Drools Workbench and external integrations (if needed) with pros and cons. We're wondering if there is a more elegant approach.

Approaches to limiting a decision table to fire only if a field value matches one of a long list of potential lookup values (hts codes):

1. Hardcode list of hts codes to match in each row in decision spreadsheet in a condition column

   - Pros:

     - Single place to manage reference data for rule
   - Cons:

     - Redundant information on each row of spreadsheet
     - Messy to manage long comma separated list of match values in a spreadsheet cell
2. Managed enumeration of HTS codes in drools workbench used in condition column of rule spreadsheet

   - Pros:

     - Manage the HTS list in Drools Workbench, enumerations are simple to manage
   - Cons:

     - Different mechanism (less convenient?) for managing HTS list than for managing other rule conditions (everything else in uploaded spreadsheet, HTS list managed directly in workbench)
3. Chained decision tables: 1 decision table has list of hts codes for rule and sets flag tat causes rule table to fire

   - Pros:

     - Manage HTS list in spreadsheet same as rest of rule - consistent management
   - Cons:

     - Two spreadsheets for each rule with HTS / product category filter
4. List of HTS codes stored in and managed in database, loaded dynamically as enumeration or via data object, rules in spreadsheet

   - Pros:

     - Consistent with current custom approach - upload hts spreadsheet to custom ui which is loaded into enumeration which is referenced in drools rule spreadsheet
   - Cons:

     - Separate interface to load enumeration spreadsheet vs main rule sheet
     - Custom UI outside of workbench
5. Rule template rather than decision table with all rule data stored in database

   - Pros:

     - Approach to reference data consistent with existing rule engine, upload sheets, manage sheets to custom ui
     - All reference data managed same way (stored in database, uploaded via UI)
   - Cons:

     - Rules managed in separate interface from reference data (minor?)
     - Rule logic mapping inputs to bins or coefficients separate from the actual bin and coefficient data (minor?)